# How to remove a textbox and put the dropdown box in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

How to remove a textbox and put the dropdown box in asp.net

And the value that is used before in textbox, now it should take from dropdown box

Comment: Should it happen on request or a general replacement?

Comment: did you find the answer to this question? I did something similar to this not long ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select tag for this. And can get the selected value in C# using the following code

Suppose cmb is the id of your dropdown box, then

```
cmb.Items[ cmb.SelectedIndex ].Value
```

can fetch the value selected in your drop down box and

```
cmb.Items[ cmb.SelectedIndex ].Text
```

can fetch the text selected

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to use [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) and [jquery.jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin with it.